Why is window.innerWidth much larger than window.screen.width on my Android device?
My javascript code is
var txt = "Screen: " + window.screen.width + " x " + window.screen.height + " px";
txt += "<br/>Window: " + window.innerWidth + " x " + window.innerHeight + " px";

my laptop shows
Screen: 1920 x 1080 px
Window: 1920 x 929 px

but on mobile with chrome browser I get:
Screen: 412 x 869 px
Window: 980 x 1717 px    

while the device has 3040x1440 pixel (Samsung Galaxy S10) and I did not zoom the window !
and Firefox (on the same mobile) shows:
Screen: 360 x 720 px
Window: 865 x 1517 px

I expect that screen.width >= window.innerWidth on mobiles too.

This ..?

yes. After adding ""   it's better now. Still screen size is a bit larger but this may be due to the default font size on my device. Thank you.

This happens because the viewport often prevents scanning the entire screen, and different browsers have different viewports.
To fix this, you can try calculating the viewport using the window.devicePixelRatio function.
var viewportWidth = innerWidth * devicePixelRatio;
var viewportHeight = innerHeight * devicePixelRatio;
var devicePixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio;
txt += "<br/>Viewport: " + viewportWidth + " x " + viewportHeight + " px";

